# Merging quasi-duplicate rows by moving values to new columns

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a table with thousands of rows that looks somewhat like this:

| name | sub_text | sub_code | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | text1 | code1 | a_data |
| a | text2 | code2 | a_data |
| a | text3 | code3 | a_data |
| a | text4 | code4 | a_data |
| b | text1 | code1 | b_data |
| b | text2 | code2 | b_data |
| c |  |  | c_data |

These records represent people and some of them have 4 or 2 rows where only the `sub_text` and the `sub_code` values differ. There are tens of `other_data` columns (person's ID, birth date and place, etc) that are the same for those 4 or 2 rows. There are also rows that don't have any duplicates in which case the `sub_text` and `sub_code` values are empty.

I would like to convert this table into something like this:

| name | sub_text1 | sub_text2 | sub_text3 | sub_text4 | sub_code1 | sub_code2 | sub_code3 | sub_code4 | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 | code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | a_data |
| b | text1 | text2 |  |  | code1 |  |  |  | b_data |
| c |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | c_data |

I need to sort of "merge" the records so **one person only has one record** by adding the only differing values to new columns, while leaving the `other_data` fields and the people who have only one record untouched.

This is originally an Excel table and I would also need the "converted" table in Excel. I don't think Excel can do something like that so I created a database (I only have it in Access now) hoping I could do more with SQL. I can't figure out how to solve this though. Any ideas?

Comment: In Windows Excel 2010+ or Office 365, you can do this easily using Power Query.  In other versions, a VBA solution is probably easiest.

Comment: Data is not normalized for relational database schema. Rearranging data into multiple similar name fields with same kind of data is also not normalized structure. This data should probably actually be two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365, you can do this fairly easily by

- Group by the duplicated columns (`name` and `other_data` in your example)
- Then extract the combined subtable code and text columns into a delimited list
- Split that list into new columns

**To use Power Query**

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M-Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],

//Group by Name and Other Data
//  extract a delimited list of the sub_text and sub_codes
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"name", "other_data"}, {
        {"sub_text", each Text.Combine([sub_text],";"), type text},
        {"sub_code", each Text.Combine([sub_code],";"), type text}    
        }),

//split the delimited lists into separate columns.
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "sub_text", 
                Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "sub_code", 
                Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv))
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with this syntax so I'm trying to understand how it would work with my actual data. What if I have a third set of columns called `sub_lang` that has to be moved the same way? Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/hxELUes) how that would go? (Sorry, can't paste that many characters in a comment.)

Comment: @Emcs You'd add the appropriate line of code **manually** to the `#"Grouped Rows"`  function (similar to what you see) and also add an extra `Split Column` line for that sub Group.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to enumerate the rows and then use conditional aggregation.  This is easy in most databases -- using `row_number()` -- but is a pain in MS Access.  Here is one method, assuming the values in the columns have no duplicates:

```
select num, other_data,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 1, sub_text, null)) as sub_text_1,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 2, sub_text, null)) as sub_text_2,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 3, sub_text, null)) as sub_text_3,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 4, sub_text, null)) as sub_text_4,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 1, sub_code, null)) as sub_code_1,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 2, sub_code, null)) as sub_code_2,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 3, sub_code, null)) as sub_code_3,
       sum(iif(seqnum = 4, sub_code, null)) as sub_code_4
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t as t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.sub_text <= t.sub_text
             ) as seqnum
      from t
group by name, other_data;
```